# Set Recipient ID or Email in URL Parameters with PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have tried (with success) the adaptative payments and was wondering if it was possible to "bypass" it by directly specifying recipient information in a /myaccount/transfer/send link in URL parameters like so

https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/transfer/send/**external?recipient=john.doe%40gmail.com&amount=25&currencyCode=EUR**

I want, as a third party, to be able to initiate a payment towards a given e-mail address (not mine) from any Paypal user

Answer (score -1):

The following URL worked for me:

```
https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/transfer/buy/external?recipient=john.doe%40gmail.com&amount=25&currencyCode=EUR
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18198606)

Comment: You're right in general, but there is nothing to add in that case, because I found the right url by trial and error. Unfortunately PayPal tends to change their API all the time :(

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn’t work as of 2019, still looking for a solution.

Comment: Since two years, the link `https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/transfer/homepage/external/profile?amount=9.05&currencyCode=EUR&recipient=my@mail.com&note=myNote` was working perfect. Stopped working since a week or so. No altrernative at this moment :(